# VueI18n can't read or change locale in Composition API

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, vue-i18n

I am using VueI18n in my Vue app, which uses the Composition API. As such, I am trying to follow the [**VueI18n Composition documentation**](https://vue-i18n.intlify.dev/guide/advanced/composition.html#composition-api).

I18n creation :

```
import { createI18n } from "vue-i18n";

const i18n = createI18n({
  legacy: false,           // to use with Composition API
  globalInjection: true,   // to inject in the component
  messages: loadLocaleMessages(),
  locale: navigator.language.split("-")[0] || "en",
  fallbackLocale: "en",
});

export default i18n;
```

Adding to app :

```
import router from "./router";
import i18n from "./translations";

const app = createApp(App);
app.use(router);
app.use(i18n);
app.mount("#app");

export default app;
```

Using VueI18n (where the problem occurs) :

```
import { useI18n } from "vue-i18n";

export default defineComponent({
  setup() {
    const { t, locale } = useI18n({ useScope: 'global' });

    console.log(locale);        // fr
    console.log(locale.value);  // undefined

    locale.value = 'en';    // TypeError: can't assign to property "value" on "fr": not an object
    ...
```

The problem is about the `locale` property. [**I know**](https://vue-i18n.intlify.dev/guide/advanced/composition.html#global-scope-1) it is of type `WritableComputedRef<string>` and should be get/set through `locale.value`. However, it returns `undefined` when read and fails with a `TypeError` when changed.

Also why would printing `locale` only in the console show the value ?

Thanks in advance for any help.
I will gladly bring more explanations and context if necessary.

Comment: It's safe to assume that you don't use the version the documentation applies to. From what I see, the latest is supposed to work the way it's documented

Comment: I wish it was the case, but I am using the v9.2.2 and the documentation states to be valid for versions v9.x. I am a bit lost I have to say.

Comment: Not reproducible https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-7fn21z

Comment: I am reassured to see what I did is correct. The problem must be elsewhere then. Thanks for taking the time to reproduce, I'll keep this post up-to-date if I find my mistake.

Comment: Check with your eyes there are correct versions in node_modules `vue-i18n` and `@intlify/vue-i18n-core` own package.json  files, the modules could be messed up during an upgrade or else

Comment: I checked and `vue-i18n` and `@intlify/core-base` both have the v9.2.2 (same for `@intlify/vue-devtools`). I however don't specifically have a `@intlify/vue-i18n-core` package I have to say.

Comment: @EstusFlask In case you are interested, the problem was because I setup VueI18n for Composition API only, when my app is currently still migrating from Options API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, something very important I failed to mention is that I'm working on app which is originally in Options API. We are however currently working on migrating, and any new components are Composition API.

I wrongly assumed that switching VueI18n to Composition API, would still be backward-compatible with Options API. But it obviously is not.

To successfully manage this migration, I should have followed the [**Vue I18n - Migration in Vue 3**](https://vue-i18n.intlify.dev/guide/migration/vue3.html#migration-to-composition-api-from-legacy-api) documentation. Here it states to set `legacy` and `allowComposition` to `true` in order for VueI18n to work with both APIs in the same app.

```
import { createI18n } from "vue-i18n";

const i18n = createI18n({
  allowComposition: true,  // to use with Composition API
  legacy: true,           // so that VueI18n still works with Options API
  globalInjection: true,   // to inject in the component
  messages: loadLocaleMessages(),
  locale: navigator.language.split("-")[0] || "en",
  fallbackLocale: "en",
});

export default i18n;
```

The documentation does precise, however, that this solution is meant to migrate from Options to Composition and will be removed in the next v10 upgrade.